# $\limsup\limits_k \{\omega : X_k(\omega)>a\}=\{\omega : \limsup\limits_k X_k(\omega)>a\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

I was looking for connections between the limit superior and inferior of sets and the limit superior and inferior of sequences. Let $(X_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a stochastic process. Then is $\limsup\limits_k \{\omega : X_k(\omega)>a\}=\{\omega : \limsup\limits_k X_k(\omega)>a\}$ and $\liminf\limits_k \{\omega : X_k(\omega)<a\}=\{\omega : \liminf\limits_k X_k(\omega)<a\}$.

Is the following reasonning correct?

$\limsup\limits_k \{\omega : X_k(\omega)>a\}=\{X_k(\omega)>a$ for infinitely many $k\}\subset \{\omega : \limsup\limits_k X_k(\omega)>a\} $ since $X_k(\omega)>a$ for infinitely many $k\implies \limsup\limits_k X_k(\omega)>a$. The converse seems to be true also.

If $\limsup\limits_k X_k(\omega)>a$ then $X_k(\omega)>a$ for infinitely many $k$ and so $\{\limsup\limits_k X_k>a\}\subset\{X_k>a$ for infinitely many $k\}= \limsup\limits_k\{X_k>a\}$

Comment: What if $X_k(\omega)=a+1/k$? Then $X_k(\omega)>a$ for all $k$ while $\limsup_{k\to\infty} X_k(\omega)=a$.

Comment: If you are seeking a connection to sequences of numbers, have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit#Properties.

Comment: I see your point. But what about if I replace the $>$ with $\ge$?

Comment: Then the other inclusion might fail. Consider $X_k(\omega)=a-1/k$.

Comment: The question arrises in a proof where we need to show $P(\lim\limits_{t\to0} X_t=0)=1$, i.e. $\forall \epsilon>0, P(\limsup\limits_{t}|X_t|>\epsilon)=0$. For this, the author defines $t_k\to0$ and $\Delta_k:=\sup\limits_{t_{k+1}\le u\le t_{k}}X_u$ and then show by Borel-Cantelli that $P(\limsup\limits_k\{X_{t_k}>\epsilon/2\})=0$ and $P(\limsup\limits_k\{\Delta_k\ge\epsilon/2\})=0$. To conclude, he tells $\limsup\limits_t \{|X_t|>\epsilon\}\subset \{\limsup\limits_k X_{t_k}>\epsilon/2\}\cup\{\limsup\limits_k\Delta_k\ge\epsilon/2\}$. So I thought the two limit are the same

Comment: @jakobdt, I took a look at the wiki page you refer to but in [almost sure convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit#Almost_sure_convergence) part they seem to claim $\{\limsup_n|Y_n-Y|>b\}=\bigcap\limits_{n\ge1}\bigcup\limits_{j\ge n}\{|Y_j-Y|>b\}$ which seems to be in contradition with your $a+1/m$  example no?

Comment: Suppose $\omega\in\{\limsup_n|Y_n-Y|>1/k\}$. Then $\omega\in\bigcap_{n\geq1}\bigcup_{j\geq n}\{|Y_j-Y|>1/k\}$ as well. For the opposite inclusion we take $\omega\in\bigcap_{n\geq1}\bigcup_{j\geq n}\{|Y_j-Y|>1/k\}$. If e.g. $|Y_n-Y|=1/k+1/n$ we see that $\limsup_n|Y_n(\omega)-Y(\omega)|=1/k$. So we cannot conclude that $\bigcap_{n\geq1}\bigcup_{j\geq n}\{|Y_j-Y|>1/k\}\subseteq \{\limsup_n|Y_n-Y|>1/k\}$. Note, however that $\bigcap_{n\geq1}\bigcup_{j\geq n}\{|Y_j-Y|>1/k\}\subseteq \{\limsup_n|Y_n-Y|>1/{2k}\}$. Therefore, when you take the union over all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ you obtain the identity.

Comment: Thank you, it was a bit tricky